# How to eliminate duplicate entries within a stream based on a own Equal class

Tags: java, java-8, equality, java-stream

I do have a simialar problem like descripted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680157/how-to-remove-duplicate-objects-in-a-listmyobject-without-equals-hashcode). But with two differences first I do use the stream api and second I do have an `equals()` and `hashCode()` method already. But within the stream the equalitity of the of Blogs are in this context not the same as defined in the `Blog` class.

```
Collection<Blog> elements = x.stream()
    ... // a lot of filter and map stuff
    .peek(p -> sysout(p)) // a stream of Blog
    .? // how to remove duplicates - .distinct() doesn't work
```

I do have a class with an equal Method lets call it `ContextBlogEqual` with the method

```
public boolean equal(Blog a, Blog b);
```

Is there any way removing all duplicate entries with my current stream approach based on the `ContextBlogEqual#equal` method?

I thought already on grouping, but this doesn't work either, because the reason why `blogA` and `blogB` is equal isn't just one parameter. Also I have no idea how I could use .reduce(..), because there is useally more than one element left.

Comment: Is your method `equal` or `equals` ? Could you add the equals implementation  here in your question ?

Comment: You can map the `Blog` objects to a class that wraps them and has `equals` that compares using your new equivalence, and then map them back after the `distinct`, I suppose.

Comment: @RealSkeptic this is an approach fellow has suggested. Currently the best shot I have.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, note that there should also be new `hashCode()` defined which is compatible with that equals implementation. I'd vote for collecting into `TreeSet` with custom comparator. Also note the [JDK-8072723](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072723) bug which is actually the thing the OP wants.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23699371/2711488

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In essence, you either have to define `hashCode` to make your data work with a hashtable, or a total order to make it work with a binary search tree.

For hashtables you'll need to declare a wrapper class which will override `equals` and `hashCode`.

For binary trees you can define a `Comparator<Blog>` which respects your equality definition and adds an arbitrary, but consistent, ordering criterion. Then you can collect into a `new TreeSet<Blog>(yourComparator)`.

Answer (score 1):

First, please note that `equal(Blog, Blog)` method is not enough for the most scenarios as you will need to pairwise compare all the entries which is not efficient. It's better to define the function which extracts new key from the blog entry. For example, let's consider the following `Blog` class:

```
static class Blog {
    final String name;
    final int id;
    final long time;

    public Blog(String name, int id, long time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, id, time);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Blog other = (Blog) obj;
        return id == other.id && time == other.time && Objects.equals(name, other.name);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name+":"+id+":"+time;
    }
}
```

Let's have some test data:

```
List<Blog> blogs = Arrays.asList(new Blog("foo", 1, 1234), 
        new Blog("bar", 2, 1345), new Blog("foo", 1, 1345), 
        new Blog("bar", 2, 1345));
List<Blog> distinctBlogs = blogs.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(distinctBlogs);
```

Here `distinctBlogs` contains three entries: `[foo:1:1234, bar:2:1345, foo:1:1345]`. Suppose that it's undesired, because we don't want to compare the `time` field. The simplest way to create new key is to use `Arrays.asList`:

```
Function<Blog, Object> keyExtractor = b -> Arrays.asList(b.name, b.id);
```

The resulting keys already have proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementations.

Now if you fine with terminal operation, you may create a custom collector like this:

```
List<Blog> distinctByNameId = blogs.stream().collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(
                keyExtractor, Function.identity(), 
                (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new),
                map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())));
System.out.println(distinctByNameId);
```

Here we use `keyExtractor` to generate the keys and merge function is `(a, b) -> a` which means select the previously added entry when repeating key appears. We use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the order (omit this parameter if you don't care about order). Finally we dump the map values into the new `ArrayList`. You can move such collector creation to the separate method and generalize it:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> distinctBy(
        Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(keyExtractor, Function.identity(), (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new),
        map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values()));
}
```

This way the usage will be simpler:

```
List<Blog> distinctByNameId = blogs.stream()
           .collect(distinctBy(b -> Arrays.asList(b.name, b.id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you'll need a helper method like this one:

```
static <T, U> Stream<T> distinct(
    Stream<T> stream, 
    Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor
) {
    final Map<U, String> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return stream.filter(t -> seen.put(keyExtractor.apply(t), "") == null);
}
```

It takes a `Stream`, and returns a new `Stream` that contains only distinct values given the `keyExtractor`. An example:

```
class O {
    final int i;
    O(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "O(" + i + ")";
    }
}

distinct(Stream.of(new O(1), new O(1), new O(2)), o -> o.i)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This yields

```
O(1)
O(2)
```

#### Disclaimer

As commented by [Tagir Valeev here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383428/how-to-eliminate-duplicate-entries-within-a-stream-based-on-a-own-equal-class/32414892?noredirect=1#comment52705664_32414892) and [in this similar answer by Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/521799), this approach has flaws. The operation as implemented here...

- is unstable for ordered parallel streams
- is not optimal for sequential streams
- violates the stateless predicate constraint on [`Stream.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)

#### Wrapping the above in your own library

You can of course extend `Stream` with your own functionality and implement this new `distinct()` function in there, e.g. like [`jOOλ`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) or [Javaslang](http://javaslang.com/) do:

```
Seq.of(new O(1), new O(1), new O(2))
   .distinct(o -> o.i)
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Practically the same as proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/4856258). And has the same problems.

Comment: @TagirValeev: Thanks for the link. Those are good points in general, although in specific situations, the problems might be neglected. Nonetheless, I'll update my answer to document this restriction