# Select distinct objects by custom field via Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to convert Java loop code to Java 8 stream.
I have an `ArrayList` of `Row` objects that should sum all `deliveredLength` excluding the `Row` objects that has the same content as another `Row` object that has the same content.

Java Loops

```
public int getDeliveredLength() {
    List<Row> distinct = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Row row : rows) {
        if (sameContent(distinct, row)) {
            continue;
        }
        distinct.add(row);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (Row row : distinct) {
        sum += row.getDeliveredLength();
    }
    return sum;
}

private boolean sameContent(List<Row> list, Row other) {
    for (Row row : list) {
        if (other.sameContent(row)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What would the Java 8 stream code be?

```
public int getDeliveredLength() {
  return rows.stream().filter(??).map(??).mapToInt(Row::getDeliveredLength).sum()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Got some errors?

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27870136/4856258) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32383428/4856258) question.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you write a new method `sameContent`, and do you not override the `equals` method? Using `equals` has the advantage that many classes and methods from the standard library call it to compare instances of your class.

Given that you use `equals`, you can use the standard `Stream.distinct()` method, which returns a stream of distinct values. So your Java 8 stream expression becomes:

```
rows.stream().distinct().mapToInt(Row::getDeliveredLength).sum()
```

Comment: `Row ` might be defined not only by its content. For example its index

Comment: Row contains start, end and comment and content, so equals and hashcode need to include all fields. sameContent() only check the content-field

Comment: Or `Row` is from an external library. It is possible to wrap it into a custom object having the proper equals / hashCode though, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23699499/1743880)